# How do you say rolling's one's eyes or describe an eye roll in this situation?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

How would you describe this situation:

> Rolling one's eyes due to orgasm.

I checked most English dictionaries but most definitions are negative, e.g. due to frustration.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You can roll your eyes for any number of reasons. Aside from the fact that it's not a complete sentence, what issue do you have with the construction of "rolling one's eyes"?

Comment: Yes, and how is this not purely a question of style, please?

Comment: This question should be closed (and eventually deleted) as being 'unclear what you're asking'.

Comment: Give me a break. Rolling one's eyes is rolling ones eyes.

Answer (score 1):

### "X's eyes rolled back (in his/her head)".

It's true that the expression "X rolled his/her eyes" is often associated with frustration or sarcasm.

A more neutral way of describing this expression is to say that "X's eyes rolled back", or "X's eyes rolled back in his/her head". This may refer to someone who is falling unconscious for whatever reason (e.g. it seems to show up fairly often in descriptions of "demonic possession"-type scenarios), but it's also used in erotic literature to describe the situation that you specified:

- > Her head and **eyes rolled back**, and she lost focus as the exquisite spasms erupted from her core and spread outward.

  (p. 196, *[My Way Back to You](https://books.google.com/books?id=368YBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA196),* by Pamela Hearon, 2015)
- > **Her eyes rolled back in her head** as he watched her climax, and a low moan escaped her throat.

  (p. 566, *[Dangerous Trust](https://books.google.com/books?id=YTKLAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA566),* by Cynthia Monet, 2009)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you're after, but the term I would use to describe this (as opposed to what my teenage daughter does pretty much any time I open my mouth) is:

> **La Petite Mort**

or "*the little death*" in English.  [Wikipedia describes it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_petite_mort) as:

> La petite mort is an expression which means "the brief loss or weakening of consciousness" and in modern usage refers specifically to "the sensation of orgasm as likened to death."

I recall coming across a photography project on the internet titled *La Petite Mort* that consisted of photos of people's faces as they reached orgasm, but the closest I could find now was [a similar book](https://amzn.to/2utp1JU) by a Canadian photographer with the same name.

---